# In Django I want to fetch product info from database to Html template I tried for loop but didn work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

While making E-commerce website i Create Datbase model and fetch product to html page but when i created For loop for fetching product it doesn't work here is my code for View.py

```
def index(request):
    produts = Product.objects.all()
    n = len(produts)    
    n_slide = n//4 + ceil((n/4)-(n//4))  
    parms = {'no_of_slides':n_slide,'range':range(1,n_slide),'produt':produts}
    return render(request,"shop/index.html",parms)
```

This is My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_desc = models.CharField(max_length= 80)
    product_price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    prodct_pub_date = models.DateField()
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="shop/images",default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/',include("shop.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my html code for index page

```
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<div class="container">
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      
      {% for i in range %}

      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="{{i}}" ></li>
      
      {% endfor %}
   
     </ul>

    <!--Slideshow starts here -->
    <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">

      <div class="carousel-item active">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src='{% static "shop/h2.jpeg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{produt.0.product_name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{produt.0.product_desc}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>

        {% for i in Product|slice:"1:" %}

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src='{% static "shop/h1.png" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{i.product_desc}}</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
        
        {% endif %}

        </div><div class="carousel-item">

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- left and right controls for the slide -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        .carousel-control-prev-icon

    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>


{% endblock %}

</div>
```

i want to fetch product information from Datbase and upload all product info with for loop automatically.and also uplaod images

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for i in Product|slice:"1:" %}
```

should be

```
{% for i in produt|slice:"1:" %}
```

because the query-set is named `produt` in the `parms` context